# Is there a method to find how to combine resistors in order to get a specific resistance?

Tags: resistors

I was working on this [homework](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-002-circuits-and-electronics-spring-2007/assignments/hw1.pdf):

> Using only 1k resistors, synthesize a  resistor of 3/5k and a 
>   resistor of 5/3k. Use no more than four 1k resistors in each case.

I found how to do it but I'm not sure I used the efficient method. Indeed, I listed all the different ways to combine four resistors and computed the total resistance of each of them.

Does it exist a fastest method to find the good combination? Or does it exist some tables where the work is already done?

Comment: There is this website... https://www.qsl.net/in3otd/parallr.html but for homework it's called cheating.

Comment: I don't think you are expected to use any particularly efficient method for hand-calculating (not to say a faster method doesn't exist), the question just expect you to do a frustrating exercise on serial resistors and parallel resistors to ensure that you understand the calculations (after all, it's the first homework for Chapter 1). It's likely that you won't see the same question again in the future, when you move to more advanced concepts. In practice, if it's needed, a calculator is always used.